# Display the username using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble getting the name of the logged in person to display.

I am trying to get to show the right name by the user that is logged in.
this is the session thats been set to set the Username (Gebruikersnaam):

```
$_SESSION["USER"] = $result["Gebruikersnaam"];
```

I was trying something like this:

```
$test = $_SESSION['USER'];
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM klant 
 WHERE klant.Gebruikersnaam = $test
"; 

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['USER'])) { 
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $klant){ ?>
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo $klant['Voorletters']. " " .$klant['Tussenvoegsel']. " " .$klant['Tussenvoegsel']; ?></p>
<?php
} } ?>
```

But this isnt doing the trick it will give me this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'jan' in 'where clause' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php:55 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php(55): PDO->query('SELECT *
>   FROM k...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\auto.php(2):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php on line 55

**UPDATE**

the following code works half.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE Gebruikersnaam = :name";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute([':name' => $test]);
$data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

this works but the only problem I have right now is this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['USER'])) { 
        foreach ($db->query($data) as $klant){ ?>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo $klant['Voorletters']. " " .$klant['Tussenvoegsel']. " " .$klant['Tussenvoegsel']; ?></p>
<?php
} } ?>
```

This will give me this error:

> Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php on line 61
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php on line 61

I know what the problem is (that it only gives you 1 thing back) but I don't know what to do next so I can get the right Name (Voorletters,Tussenvoegsel) bu the user.

Comment: Try `Gebruikersnaam` instead of `klant.Gebruikersnaam`

Comment: You need to escape sql parameters. PHP uses PDO for that among many other libraries. Especially in the case of security concerns e.g. sql injection attacks.

Comment: Tried that but didnt fix it. Is still the same.

Comment: It seems unlikely that naam is an integer . More likely to be a string

Comment: Topicstarter hint try to program in english only also makes sharing the code online if you have bugs alot more easy to read and understand for non dutch speaking programmers... Mixing english and dutch keywords in programming is a bit sloppy.. "It seems unlikely that naam is an integer . More likely to be a string" Yes @Strawberry `naam` is dutch for `name` you are right about that one that's it is a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Column not found` indicates that you are using some column name that does not exist in DB.

Problem is here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klant.Gebruikersnaam = $test";
```

Your `$test` value is `jan` and it's not column name. So it needs quotes around: `[...] = '$test'`, but it's wrong/insecure way.

Use prepared statement for these queries to also solve SQL Injection:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE Gebruikersnaam = :name";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute([':name' => $test]);
$data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: If i use the prepared statement that you were suggesting it gives me this error msg:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php:39 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\index.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php on line 39"

Comment: `execute` instead of `query` with `PDOStatement`

Comment: If I use 'execute' it still wil give me an error tho:
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':name' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php:59 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php(59): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM k...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\index.php(2): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\topmenu.php on line 59

Comment: Where is the `prepare`?

Comment: I did this: '$data = $db->prepare($sql)->execute([':name' => $test]);' like you said me to. @DarkBee

Comment: @DarkBee Thx bud! this works but can check my Question again because the query works now but it the problem is still not fixed.

Comment: Inspect the data u've got from the database `var_dump($data)` - `fetch` will only return one row. This means you don't need the foreach there